# C# - Make Mouse Cursor Invisible

Tags: c#, cursor, mouse, hide, keylogger

I tried to make the mouse cursor invisible using the following code:

```
Cursor.Hide();
```

The mouse cursor does disappear from the screen and it does not appear in video captured using Expression Encoder 4.

PrintScreen is useless since it does not show the mouse cursor anyway.  However, I installed a keylogger on my system and the mouse is visible in screenshots taken by the keylogger, even though it is not visible to the user on the screen.

How is this possible?  How can I make the mouse cursor invisible to the keylogger as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "it was still able to capture the mouse". You haven't made your mouse disappear, you just hid the cursor, the computer still gets information about the position and which buttons are pressed.

Comment: Your mouse is still existent, it's just not visible. So when you move the mouse and press, it will still work as usual.
I don't think it's possible to "kill" the mouse, because then you could easily kill every system (security).

Comment: I don't think you understood me.  Even though the mouse is not visible to the user, the mouse cursor is visible in the screenshot taken by the keylogger (as if it were never hidden in the first place)

Comment: Maybe the software of your keylogger creates it's own mousepicture and places it on the screenshot afterwars (gets position of the mouse).
It's very difficult to tell something if you don't know what the programm does exactly.

Comment: I agree with Janes, what program is this? Also, a couple of screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of elegance here, but you could just create a completely transparent cursor file, and tell your application to use this custom cursor...according to the OS, it's still there and visible, but you won't see it.

Comment: The program is called iSafe Free Keylogger and can be downloaded from here: http://download.cnet.com/iSafe-Free-Keylogger/3000-2162_4-75891050.html

Comment: @series0ne The transparent cursor you are talking about is an image created using Photoshop?

Comment: Is it meant to be transparent to this particular keylogger, or keyloggers in general?

Comment: @JamieKelly Well I want it to be transparent to keyloggers in general.

Comment: Ah well as per my answer below, you won't be able to stop some of them completely.

Comment: @JamieKelly What else can be done then?  An alternative would be to create an onscreen keyboard where each key is mapped to another key (for example, a is mapped to c).  Then in the lower portion of the onscreen keyboard I would have a visually encrypted remapping key.  What do you think?

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to do. I'd recommend starting a new question with exactly what you're trying to achieve, and the methods you've tried.

Comment: @Matthew, it needs to be a .cur file. Not sure if you can create this with Photoshop. I use Aha-Soft ArtIcons for such purposes.

Comment: @Matthew, be aware that the "invisible" cursor will only display inside your application. It will not be invisible globally, throughout the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A keylogger may be programmed to take a screenshot and then insert the cursor image by itself using the position and cursor type. You will not be able to stop this from happening if this is the case.

Comment: This is quite speculative and not an answer since you don't know what the program does exactly.

Comment: Apologies, it was meant as a general statement, I'll edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running WPF applications, try this at runtime (when you capture screen):

```
    this.Cursor = Cursors.None;
```

See also [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/28b71115-5a30-4811-a26a-80abfb53facb/).